# How to get the maximum number of columns present in a file in perl

Tags: perl, file

I have a test.csv file which has data something like this.

```
"a","usa","24-Nov-2011","100.98","Extra1","Extra2"
"B","zim","23-Nov-2011","123","Extra22"
"C","can","23-Nov-2011","123"
```

I want to fetch the maximum number of columns in this file (i,e 6 in this case) and then store this in a variable.

Like

```
 Variable=6
```

Can you provide me some suggestions on how to proceed.

Answer (score 5):

Try using [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV)

Read each line through, parse through this module, and compare the number of fields to your variable.

```
#!/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new;
my $max = 0;

open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", "test.csv" or die "test.csv: $!";
while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) ) {
    my $count = scalar @$rows;
    $max = $count > $max ? $count : $max;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the main reasons given why people use `split` on a CSV file rather than `Text::CSV` is that `Text::CSV` isn't a standard Perl module, so it might not be available.

Then use [Text::ParseWords](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/ParseWords.html). This is a standard module ans should be readily available:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use Text::ParseWords qw(quotewords);

my $keep = 0;
for my $line ( <DATA> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my @columns = quotewords ("\s*,\s*", $keep, $line );
    say "<" . join( ">  <", @columns ) . ">";
}
__DATA__
"a","usa","24-Nov-2011","100.98","Extra1","Extra2"
"B","zim","23-Nov-2011","123","Extra22"
"C","can","23-Nov-2011","123"
"D","can, can, can","23-Nov-2011","123"
```

This produces:

```
<a>  <usa>  <24-Nov-2011>  <100.98>  <Extra1>  <Extra2>
<B>  <zim>  <23-Nov-2011>  <123>  <Extra22>
<C>  <can>  <23-Nov-2011>  <123>
<D>  <can, can, can>  <23-Nov-2011>  <123>
```

Note that the commas inside the quotes didn't throw off the parsing. Now, there are no more excuses for using `split`.